# Image view out of page towards the right unexpectedly

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I am rendering a simple view. It consists of an image on the right and some text on the left. This is how it looks like:

```
return (
      <View style={styles.companyContainerStyle}>
        <View>
          <Text>{this.props.companyNameAr}</Text>
          <Text>{this.props.descriptionAr}</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.imageContainerStyle}>
          <Image
            style={styles.imageStyle}
            source={{ uri: this.props.logo }}
            resizeMode='contain'
            resizeMethod='auto'
          />
        </View>
      </View>
    );
```

The following is the styles I applied to make the text and image aligned next to each other:

```
const styles = {
  companyContainerStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    padding: 10
  },
  imageContainerStyle: {
    borderRadius: 5,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#2279b4',
    padding: 1,
  },
  imageStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
  }
}
```

The very weird part is that it looks like this on the emulator: 
[image]

I think the length of the text is pushing the image to the very right out of the screen. I thought that the number of lines would adjust accordingly to fit everything in the screen. However its not the case. How do I make everything look neat given that the length of the text is unknown (it is being rendered from a database)??

Comment: giving a fixed width in percentage to text content can solve your problem. And also give fixed width and height to img in percentage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `flex: 1` to `imageContainerStyle` and also add `flex: 1` to `View` that is container of the two `Text` components.

Reason for this is that if the `Text` component does not have container with `flex: 1` on it the text will try to take all possible space. The container will restrict that

Comment: adding a flex to the view of the text did the trick! when I added a flex 1 to the image container though its width increased.

Answer (score 1):

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 70%;
  height: 400px;;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
}
#top_content {
display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
#para {
  width: 60%;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 0px;
  
  
}
img {
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="top_content">
    <p id="para">adfasdfadf sadfdaafafdasdfadfadfadfdfad dasadfadfadfadfadgvfa sasadasdaf asdfdfdadfadf</p>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" alt="myimg">  
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Something like this can make sure that your text will not push your img outside